# VS 2012 Debugger, modules loaded twice, breakpoint couldn't be hit

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2012, c++-cli

I have a Visual Studio 2012 solution which contains two projects, 1st is `C++/CLI` wrapper and the 2nd is `C#`, where I use the wrapped dll. Both projects are in 32 bit debug mode. In C# project `Enable native code debugging` option is enabled. In C++/CLI debugging mode is set to `mixed`.

The problem is that in both projects the breakpoints can't be hit. I followed advices from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155930/fixing-the-breakpoint-will-not-currently-be-hit-no-symbols-have-been-loaded-fo) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3325588/mixed-mode-assembly-not-loading-symbol-for-native-c-pdbs) but without luck.

The most interesting thing, that bot projects are loaded twice, the locations are the same and symbols files are loaded from the same directory, there exe and dll are placed. It's also interesting why Tester is loaded with and without symbols.

[image: Debug-Module window]

Can someone help me fix it please?